# Select timestamp for one date and for a period time on the same field in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My query on the table require the condition as below:

Table:

```
user_id || amount || date
1       || 10     || 2019-04-01
1       || 25     || 2019-04-02
3       || 25     || 2019-04-04
1       || 25     || 2019-04-03
```

Expect result: get user_id, date, amount of date, amount of month (sum all amount of date of user_id in month)

input parameter: user_id, date, start date of month, end date of month.

ex: user_id = 1, date = 2019-04-02, start_date_of_month = 2019-04-01, end_date_of_month = 2019-04-30

```
user_id || amount_of_date || date       || amount_of_month
1       || 25             || 2019-04-02 || 60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select user_id, 
       max(case when date=@inputdate then amount end) as amount_of_Date,
       min(case when date=@inputdate then date end) as date,
       sum(amount) as amount_of_month
from tablename
where user_id=1 and date between '2019-04-01' and '2019-04-30'
group  by user_id
```